# Django template if inside a for loop - Invalid block tag on line 13: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'.

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% for letter in "ABCD"|make_list %}
{% if letter == A or D}
Yes
{% else %}
No
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

With my django template I am getting the following error message:
Invalid block tag on line 13: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?  I don't understand what is wrong here. Can someone point out why I'm getting this error?

Comment: It should be `{% if letter == A or letter == D %}`

Comment: Geia sou Paulo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the `if` template tag correctly. You are closing with `}`, whereas it needs `%}`.

Try this:

```
{% for letter in "ABCD"|make_list %}

    {% if letter == 'A' or letter == 'D' %}
        Yes
    {% else %}
        No
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, well spotted.

Comment: In PyCharm i ran code inspector and it didn't pick it up. Is there some other way to show these typos?

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + s` and navigate to `Languages & Frameworks --> Python Template Languages`. In there choose (for the HTML) the `Django` template language (spotted at the very top). Click OK.